# Encrypt some string with several Public Keys and decrypt with any of Private key?

Tags: cryptography

I need to encrypt some string, let's say "Hello world" with several Public Keys and be able to decrypt this hash with any of Private Keys. Could you please tell if it possible and if so, the way to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at [Smair's Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) scheme with ***k=1***. Though I'm not sure if it's possible to derive a secret from predefined Stellar secret keys.

Comment: It does not work with k=1. I've already checked this option..

Answer (score 0):

It's possible quiet in a different way, I have been working on a similar implementation. I'm not sure if this may be useful to you but the way I have implemented is like this,

1. Create a data key pair `private(data) pub(data)`
2. Encrypt the data with data private key `private(data)`
3. create multiple key pairs, `private(Alice) pub(Alice)`, `private(Bob) pub(Bob)`
4. Encrypt the private(data) with Alice's and Bob's public key
5. You can share encrypted data and encrypted private(data) with Alice and Bob
6. Alice can decrypt the `private(data)` with `private(Alice`) and than decrypt Data with decrypted `private(data)`
7. Bob can decrypt the `private(data)` with `private(Bob)` and than decrypt Data with decrypted `private(data)`

Comment: Thank you, this can be an option, but here is much better implementation. I didn't check it yet, but it looks good - you don't need to store encrypted parts several times, but instead, you can store encrypted content keys. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/4577/190816

Comment: Hmm I believe my answer is same as that question you linked, just answered in a different way.